# Lubuntu Desktop icons, auto arrange and lock workaround

Tags: lubuntu, icons

On lubuntu 12.04 align to grid is working but I can't really lock desktop icon, they move around if any user drag them, there isn't a working option to lock them to a fixed position.

Searching the web for a solution did not help me so I'm here asking.
My thoughts about a possible solution is to use cron daemon to launch periodically a *select all desktop icon and align to *grid* command*, at least they will return on top left alignment, not perfect but something.

I' m not an expert so my concern about this is .

how I put align to grid in a terminal ?

I don't know where to look, I tried looking in the log file of xorg, I only know that that action is triggered by right clicking on icons and selecting align to grid but terminal command is another story

Answer (score 0):

This is not my answer, but "Solution for Lubuntu(PCManFM):"

go to `/home/USER/.config/pcmanfm/default/` or `/home/USER/.config/pcmanfm/lubuntu/`.

change USER with your user name

```
sudo nano pcmanfm.conf
```

go to section "[desktop]", change `sort_by` to `sort_by=2` (if you want to sort by name)

log out -> log in

I'm not an expert, probably there is some nicer way to do that with bash script or something..but this works and it is needed to be done only once. About sorting numbers I'm not sure which one is for what and didn't find any useful info, so you'll need to discover it by yourself by playing or finding some info.

I'm not sure would something similar work for Ubuntu and nautilus.